# Is it possible to retrieve the names of all my "liked videos" from my YouTube account?

Tags: youtube, youtube-playlist

I would like to have a list of the names of all the videos I "liked" on YouTube.

So far, I opened in my web browser the page with all my "liked" videos in the playlist section. I loaded all the page and then went to get the source code. With a Python script I retrieve the names from the JSON file I extracted from the source code but I only got the 100 first videos.

Python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

# Reading data back
with open('./utubelikes.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


videos = data["contents"]["twoColumnBrowseResultsRenderer"]["tabs"][0]["tabRenderer"]["content"]["sectionListRenderer"]["contents"][0]["itemSectionRenderer"]["contents"][0]["playlistVideoListRenderer"]["contents"]

for i in videos:
    if (i["playlistVideoRenderer"]["title"].get("simpleText")):
        print i["playlistVideoRenderer"]["title"]["simpleText"]

print len(videos)
```

Any idea on how to get the whole list of names?

<sub>I could go copy the content of the page and edit by hand but it would take too much time (1000+ videos).</sub>

Comment: Yes, thank you! It is exactly what I am looking for!

Comment: @pnuts : add this as an answer.

Comment: Ok I will start writing the answer... While I'm at it, how should I give you the credit of the answer? Tag you with @pnuts or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/settings/takeout) allows to download an archive of your Google's data.

- Select YouTube
- Precise playlists
- Choose the JSON format
- Click 'Next'

Once your archive created, download and extract it. You can find a JSON file `Takeout/YouTube/playlists/_J_aime_.json` that lists all the names of the videos 'liked'.

With a simple Python script :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

# Reading data back
with open('Takeout/YouTube/playlists/_J_aime_.json', 'r') as f:
    data = json.load(f)


for video in data:
        print video["snippet"]["title"]
```